# Handling In-App Purchases made via App Store Promotion

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store

In App Store Connect, there is an *App Store Promotion* section in which you can choose to have your In-App Purchase appear on your app's product page. In that section it says, "Make sure your app supports the [SKPaymentTransactionObserver method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/2877502-paymentqueue) to process this transaction."

That link sends you to the docs for `paymentQueue(_:shouldAddStorePayment:for:)`.

So, I implemented that method as follows:

```
class StoreObserver: NSObject, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, shouldAddStorePayment payment: SKPayment, for product: SKProduct) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    ...
}
```

I'm returning `true` because, as it says in the documentation, "Return true to continue the transaction in your app."

I'm not posting the rest of my In-App Purchase code because I don't think it's relevant to my question: **Is there anything else besides returning `true` that I need to do inside this method to correctly complete an In-App Purchase initiated on the App Store?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling around a bit, I found [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/promoting_in-app_purchases), which seems to answer my question: No, there's nothing else you need to do; returning `true` or `false` should do it, assuming the rest of your IAP code is set up correctly.

From the article:

> To continue an in-app purchase transaction, implement the delegate
> method in the SKPaymentTransactionObserver protocol and return true.
> StoreKit then displays the payment sheet, and the user can complete
> the transaction.

Comment: The only other thing you might want to do is show some UI to the user letting them know you are processing their purchase, but that is up to you.